# I don't know how to fix this error when installing homebrew and mingw

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, mingw-w64

I was trying to install mingw-w64 with homebrew to use C++ on my Macbook (intel chip).
I followed a tutorial I found on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhGnYWplLVo&t=310s
Everything was going well until the terminal won't show up anything about the installation. It was at this specific point when I was installing homebrew:

```
==> Tapping homebrew/core
remote: Enumerating objects: 1148169, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 1148169 (delta 2), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 1148162
Receiving objects: 100% (1148169/1148169), 455.12 MiB | 5.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (793326/793326), done.
```

I tried typing something but it didn't seem to response. So I pressed Control+C and it worked normal again.
I wasn't sure if the installation was successful or not (later on I found that when the installation is done then it will appear this line: `==> Installation successful!`)
I then used this command `brew install MinGW-w64` to instal MinGW and got this error

```
Tapped 3967 casks (4,038 files, 309.3MB).
Warning: No available formula with the name "mingw-w64".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I tried uninstalling homebrew and then installed it again but nothing worked.
I also used `brew config` and `brew doctor` and these are the inputs

```
Macs-MacBook-Air:~ mac$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.3.16-55-g377ac64
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 377ac6475c8785dc80d50df3c6b173065d32183d
Last commit: 13 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
Core tap HEAD: 377ac6475c8785dc80d50df3c6b173065d32183d
Core tap last commit: 13 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 4
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.8/bin/ruby
CPU: quad-core 64-bit broadwell
Clang: 10.0.1 build 1001
Git: 2.20.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 10.14.6-x86_64
CLT: 10.3.0.0.1.1562985497
Xcode: N/A
Macs-MacBook-Air:~ mac$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1.


Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core

Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.
```

Comment: "install mingw-w64 with homebrew to use C++ on my Macbook" - why? Install XCode and its command line tools.

Comment: On a side note, the vast majority of youtube tutorials aren't worth what you're paying for them.

Comment: You can compile and run C++ programs on macOS, without any of this bizarre procedure. Install Xcode and its command-line tools. Then use `clang++` to compile.